# Merge two cloned databases back to the Master DB (MSSQL)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, merge

Database type is MSSQL. The website tech is PHP.

Scenario: I have one master database at the office. It is cloned twice and sent off to two different events across the world. The data is changed, new data is added, some data is deleted in both of the cloned databases.

The events end and both of the cloned databases come back to the office. My task is now to merge the databases back into one Master database.

Things I Understand:

1. If data from the same row was modified on both clones a (human) decision will need to be made to decide which to take.
2. This Master, clone and back to master will be a common occurrence.
3. Since there are many tables there are lots of referencing within. I need to ensure when the data is injected into the master database the referencing holds.

**Can I get a few recommendations on how to approach this situation?**

*Note that having the various event locations access the Master Database directly is simply not a luxury I have. I have to assume each event is OFFLINE.

Comment: You are going to have to go row by row implementing logic. There is not really any more help to offer. You seem to understand pretty well what you need to do. Its just gonna be ugly boring code.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the type of situation that Merge-Replication was designed to handle. Have a look at my article series here: [Stairway to SQL Server Replication](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72401/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the type of question that you should be asking before you send out the databases.

One of the main considerations you need to look at is your primary id data type. I recommend the use of GUIDs over auto-incrementing integers, because this way new records created in the two databases won't share ids. This will make your life considerably easier.

The other thing you should look at **before** the databases are sent out is the inclusion of a timestamp column on all rows. This will also make your life considerably easier.

It's a simple matter using a guid and a timestamp to find all modified records in a table across 2-3 databases.

It's a simple matter using guids to find all new records in a table across multiple databases.